# Light bulb exploded

Tags: light

This morning, one of the lights in my house began to flicker. I didn't think much of it, and left the room to get a drink. While I was in the other room, I heard a bang, and came back to find broken glass from the flickering bulb all over the floor.

Has anyone else ever had experience of an exploding light bulb? Should I bee concerned? If I had been in the room at the time, I could have been cut by flying glass. This has never happened before in 25 years of living at my current property.

EDIT: Following advice from the comments,
can anybody explain what failure mechanism can cause a light bulb to explode? And do light bulbs often explode?

EDIT: A few more details. The metal part of the bulb remained in the light socked, with a few bits of jagged glass around it. I was able to unscrew this using pliers, but the socket has been damaged/blackened/melted, and needs replacing before a new bulb can go in. The bulb was a traditional filament bulb, and had been in place for about five or six years.

Comment: Remember: we're all here to learn, so be friendly and helpful!

Comment: "nothing to do with electronic design" - please read the question - it is exclusively about electronics

Comment: So much to speculate on, who can tell why? One thing is, when a filament burns out, the arc can result in a very large current when it dies. Never heard of that exploding a bulb, though.

Comment: @Lars Your specific questions are "Has anyone else ever had the experience of an exploding light bulb?" and "Should I be concerned?" which to me are not electronics design questions. Consumer electronics questions are generally off-topic here unless they specifically concern design matters. If you were to rephrase the first one to something like "What failure mechanism can cause a light bulb to explode?", then you'd be closer to on-topic.

Comment: @Madmanguruman Thanks for the tip - see update to question

Comment: @Lars Since the question is about failure mechanisms now, can you tell us a bit more about how the bulb exploded exactly? How did the glass connection to the metal part look like? Was the receptacle (I'm sorry, I don't know the correct term) very hot? Were its contacts clean?

Comment: *Should you be concerned?*  That depends.  Have you seen other signs of demonic posession in your house, or is this the first?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

My guess here is that there was a bad contact between the bulb and the socket. We can conclude this from the flickering part and the damage on the socket. If the contact surface between socket and the bulb is contaminated enough, you'll get arcing which will result in bulb flickering. As the arcing continues, it will corrode the contact surface making the contact even worse resulting in even more arcing.

As the process progresses, the affected area will heat up. After some time I suspect that the heat resulted in different expansion rates between the glass and the metal parts of the bulb resulting in "explosion".

In general, flickering lights are a symptom of bad contacts somewhere and should be investigated. If for example the source of arcing was a switch, it could have been very dangerous if its body softened up and someone tried to operate it.

Comment: Also I had a similar problem with a Diazed DII type fuse. I had flickering lights, UPS beeping and some directly connected computers randomly restarting. When I tracked down the problem, I found extremely hot fuse with a contaminated socket.